# Rspec return No route matches when using scoped route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a route that is defined as this in my **routes.rb** as so

```
scope ':prefix', as: :foo, controller: 'foo_paths', action: :placeholder do
  get 'foo/:id', as: 'result'
end
```

The issue is when running my test it always returns

```
 Failure/Error: subject { get :placeholder }

 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"placeholder", :controller=>"foo_paths"}
```

Here's all my code I can't find any error everything works fine in the browser and rake routes return the expected route.

**foo_paths_controller.rb**

```
class FooPathsController < ApplicationController
  def placeholder
    render nothing: true, status: :service_unavailable
  end
end
```

**foo_paths_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe FooPathsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET 'placeholder'" do
    subject { get :placeholder }

    it 'renders an empty page with service unavailable http error' do
      subject

      it { expect(subject).to have_http_status(503) }
      it { expect(subject.body).to be_blank }
    end
  end
end
```

**rake routes**

```
foo_result GET      /:prefix/foo/:id(.:format)                                                            foo_paths#placeholder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you route is saying, it has `:prefix` and `:id`. You need to specify those in subject.

```
subject { get :placeholder, prefix: 1, id: 11 }
```

Next issue i feel is, `it` is not available within `it` block. So you need to change that.

```
it 'renders an empty page with service unavailable http error' do
  subject

  expect(subject).to have_http_status(503)
  expect(subject.body).to be_blank
end
```